# Write name of imported file in sheet1

Tags: excel, vba, import, filenames

I need your help.
I have a code that import data in my Excel. Now I need to save the file name of the imported data in Sheet 1 B20.
Example: I open a Excel file named "Football123.xls." than this should be written down in Sheet1(table1) in Row B20

Thanks !

MY Code so far:

```
Sub Import1()


Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook


                                                                                                                
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse Excel & Import", FileFilter:="Excel_Datei (*.XLS*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("A:AA").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("table1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  
    OpenBook.Close False

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried to do that? Where is your issue doing it? What went wrong? What is your question (you didn't ask one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have opened the file you can use [Variable].Name, see the below addition to where you can add it.

```
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("A:AA").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("table1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("table1").Range("B20").Value = OpenBook.Name
```

```
OpenBook.Close False
```

[Variable].Name will give you the name of the file referenced.
[Variable].FullName will give you the fill file path including the file name.